# Excel-Vba : Code for Applying Formula until Last Row not working

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA so sorry if this seems to be a simple question.

I'm trying to create a macro which will formate and include a couple of formulas in a sheet but when I try to include the formula until the last row I get a error "Run Time Error 1004 - Application-Defined or Object Defined Error" at the following code:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("U2:U" & LastRow).Formula = "=L2/86400"
```

If I change the "Last Row" for a number the Macro works normally. Below is the whole code.

```
Sheets("DLASpotPlacement").Select
Dim LastRow As Double
LastRow = Sheets("DLASpotPlacement").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).Rows
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("U:U, V:V, W:W").NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss;@"
ActiveSheet.Range("U2:U" & LastRow).Formula = "=L2/86400"
ActiveSheet.Range("V2:V" & LastRow).Formula = "=VALUE(H2)"
ActiveSheet.Range("W2:W" & LastRow).FormulaLocal = "=IF(AND(H2>0,0416666666666667;H2<=0,249988425925926);""01 - 06"";IF(AND(H2>=0,25;H2<0,4166551);""06 - 10"";IF(AND(H2>=0,4166667;H2<0,4999884);""10 - 12"";IF(AND(H2>=0,5;H2<0,7499884);""12 - 18"";""18 - 01""))))"
```

Thanks for all the help

Comment: `LastRow = Sheets("DLASpotPlacement").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlup).Row`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you! I see now it was a dumb error. Now it's working perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Excel Formulas

**The error occurs because of two reasons**:

You forgot `End(xlUp)` in the `LastRow` Calculation, e.g.:

```
LastRow = Sheets("DLASpotPlacement").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

and it has to be declared as a whole number e.g.:

```
Dim LastRow as Long
```

### The Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFormulas()

    Const cCol As Variant = "A"   ' Last Row Column Letter/Number
    Const cFirstR As Long = 2     ' First Row Number

    Dim LastRow As Long           ' Last Row Number

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DLASpotPlacement")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cCol).End(xlUp).Row
        '.Cells(1, cCol).Select ' uncomment if necessary
        ' You don't need to format the entire columns.
        .Range("U" & cFirstR & ":W" & LastRow).NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss;@"
        .Range("U" & cFirstR & ":U" & LastRow).Formula = "=L2/86400"
        .Range("V" & cFirstR & ":V" & LastRow).Formula = "=VALUE(H2)"
        .Range("W" & cFirstR & ":W" & LastRow).FormulaLocal = _
                "=IF(AND(H2>0,0416666666666667;H2<=0,249988425925926);""" _
                & "01 - 06"";IF(AND(H2>=0,25;H2<0,4166551);""06 - 10"";IF(" _
                & "AND(H2>=0,4166667;H2<0,4999884);""10 - 12"";IF(AND(H2>=0" _
                & ",5;H2<0,7499884);""12 - 18"";""18 - 01""))))"
    End With

End Sub
```

### Remarks

Using `FormulaLocal` is a nice 'trick' to remember.

Answer (score 1):

@Mike;  Your problem is in this line:

```
LastRow = Sheets("DLASpotPlacement").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).Rows
```

You made the `LastRow` an array, not a number. Also, is not a Double but an  Iteger (mathematically). However, the Integer datatype is too small and you will get an "Overflow" error if you declare it "As Integer".  Here are the two changes you need to make it all work:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets("DLASpotPlacement").Rows.Count
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For LastRow, use the Worksheet.UsedRange property.

You could also use the Range.Resize property to select the range, and replace the "Select" with "With".

```
Dim LastRow As Double
With Sheets("DLASpotPlacement")
    LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.count
    .Range("U:W").NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss;@"
    .Range("U1").Resize(LastRow - 1).Formula = "=L2/86400"
    .Range("V1").Resize(LastRow - 1).Formula = "=VALUE(H2)"
    .Range("W1").Resize(LastRow - 1).FormulaLocal = "..."
End With
```